# SQOOP import error : $conditions must contain in where clause - shell command

Tags: shell, import, command, sqoop

I'm trying to make a sqoop import, so i created a shell script and then i launch it by entering parameteres in command :

**My command**

./script.sh -N 3 -D /data -C jdbc:oracle:thin:@ -Q 'select * from my_table where $CONDITIONS' -U username -M ****

But i have the folowing error despite i put a \ before $.
**Error**
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: Query [${Query}] must contain '$CONDITIONS' in WHERE clause

i don't see where is the issue, thank you for your help